# Avoiding basic auth with Selenium (using Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, firefox, selenium, basic-authentication

Well, the code is basically

```
d = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => "myApp"
d.get("http://login:password@myapp.local")
```

And still firefox shows basic auth dialog window. I use the profile setting for FF so it hopefully remembers it and lets me through, but in reality it just remembers it and you still have to hit enter.

Kinda out of ideas here.

P.S. Yes, i double checked that login:password are totally correct.

Comment: Did you try to use the firefox plugin like `Auto Auth` that inputs login details for you? You need to enter your login details manually for the first time, then from next attempt onwards the plugin handles the authentication.

Comment: Well, Auto Auth seems to have worked, but still - everybody says passing login and password in URL should do the trick and it doesn't and i feel stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Both IE and Chrome have disabled passing credentials in the url. IE in ver. 9 and Chrome as of ver 59 or 60. It looks like this may be the case in firefox as well.